# Using linq query to receive a modified List<tuple<>>

Tags: c#, linq

Do you know why this does not work?

```
List<Tuple<DateTime, DateTime, double, double>> 
   newlist = from a in this.EmployeeActivityBook
             where a.Item1 >= start && a.Item1 <= end
             select a;
```

I get this error:

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1den.png)

Comment: What does "does not work" mean?

Comment: Please see edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently returning an `IEnumerable<T>` instead of a `List<T>`, per your error.

You simply need to call `.ToList()` on your query.

```
List<Tuple<DateTime,DateTime,double,double>> newlist = 
    (from a in this.EmployeeActivityBook
     where a.Item1 >= start && a.Item1 <= end
     select a).ToList();
```

Comment: You are amazing

Comment: @JennyLee happy to help!